# Cannot install Network Manager in Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I have recently installed Debian on my laptop HP G62.

The problem is, I cannot establish a WiFi connection. I searched through the web, and I found some guide for setting up a WiFi internet connection. http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi

I got stuck on the first step: Installing the NetworkManager.

I typed in the command line as said on the web site: `aptitude install wireless-tools`, but I have the following message in the terminal:
`No packages will be installed, upgraded or removed.`

I downloaded the software on my PC, and then transferred it to my laptop, but I don't know how to install it from the path?

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your case this probably indicates that wireless-tools is already installed.

Proceed to the following steps:

```
aptitude install network-manager
aptitude install network-manager-gnome
```

(or aptitude install network-manager-kde if you have KDE instead of gnome)